# How to get return value from jquery to C# class code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a class in C#. I wants that to call jquery method from C# method with return value

I have C# class as bellow

```
public class test
{
public void get()
{
//here the code how to call jquery method with retun values
}
}
```

My jquery method is as bellow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayservices() {

return "hello";
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: do you know any method that outputs data in c#?

Comment: It´s quite unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want to call your C#-code from the client (the javascript) or vice versa? The former isn´t possible without making a server-request, as it would be quite harmful to put any weird data to your server, the latter is quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript function on client side i.e. browser and can not return value to server side function. You need to ajax call to server to pass value of javascript function.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function displayservices() {
    PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(document.getElementById("Hello", OnSuccess);
    }
    function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
      alert(response);
    }

</script>
```

Code behind.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ReceiveValueFromJS(string value)
{
     return "Value received " + value
}
```

This article [Calling ASP.Net AJAX PageMethods using ScriptManager Example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-AJAX-PageMethods-using-ScriptManager-Example.aspx) will further guide you.